# CSS background image in each corner of web browser

Tags: css

I want to place a background image in each corner of the web browser (left upper, left lower, right upper and right lower).  I placed this code in the css external style sheet:

```
body{
    /* Four background images */
    background-image:
    url(Bookclubwebsite/cornertl.jpg,
    url(Bookclubwebsite/cornertr.jpg,
    url(Bookclubwebsite/cornerbl.jpg,
    url(Bookclubwebsite/cornerbr.jpg;
    /*Their positions*/
    background-position:
    top left,
    top right,
    bottom left,
    bottom right;
    /* These apply to all images above */
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Instead I get all 4 images next to each other at the bottom of the web page.  The images don't overlap but are next to each other with space between each image from the other image.

Answer (score 2):

In order to apply, your CSS needs to be valid.

So you need to close the parenthesis of each `url()` in your `background-image` rule:

```css
body{
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/100x50),
    url(http://via.placeholder.com/100x50),
    url(http://via.placeholder.com/100x50),
    url(http://via.placeholder.com/100x50);
  background-position:
    top left,
    top right,
    bottom left,
    bottom right;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

---

Here's the exact snippet you need to copy/paste in your CSS on your website for background to work:

```
body {
  background-image: url(Bookclubwebsite/cornertl.jpg), url(Bookclubwebsite/cornertr.jpg), url(Bookclubwebsite/cornerbl.jpg),    url(Bookclubwebsite/cornerbr.jpg);
  background-position: top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Comment: It is still not working even with your code.  Here is the website:                            http://womensromanticsuspensebookclubofcalifornia.com/

Comment: @Mary, I updated my answer with exact code you need to apply to your website to make background work on `<body>`. You need to start paying close attention to every detail. The presence or absence of a single comma can break your entire website and it often does. Not closing brackets is, most times, a very serious problem. Also note broken code usually invalidates all the code following it, even if otherwise the rest would be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my CSS that is working fine for 4 background images for each corner of the web page. You can modify your CSS accordingly.

```
body { 
        background-image: url('w3css.gif'), url('w3css.gif'), url('w3css.gif'), url('w3css.gif');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: left top, right top, left bottom, right bottom;
}
```

Comment: It is still not working even with your code:  here is the website:                        http://womensromanticsuspensebookclubofcalifornia.com/

Comment: Well, you have couple of errors in your web page. Please F12 and see in console for errors to remove them.

Comment: I will.  Thank you.